# Is it possible to fix the direction of Excel's range object?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

My question is based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65123788/find-adjacent-cell-values-based-on-looked-up-cells-original-position-whilst-d).

In that question, one asks for a kind of search, and I've answered with a `VLookup` formula. The answer to that was "I would like to make this work in the reverse order", where I thought "That should be easy: just invert the range where `VLookup` runs through", but it seems not to be that simple:

Let's have a look at following two formulas:

```
=VLookup(E2;$A$2:$B$6;2;FALSE)
=VLookup(E2;$A$6:$B$2;2;FALSE)
```

Both formulas are treated as equal by Excel, and in fact, why not: in both cases I mention a rectangle, defined by the cells $A$2, $B$2, $A$6 and $B$6, to run through. So, I can't blame Excel for doing twice the same thing.
However, I mean it in another way: in the first formula, I say "Start at row 2 and go to row 6", while in the second formula I say "Start at row 6 and go down to row 2", but Excel seems not to understand this.

I like to say to Excel

> "When I give you a range, don't automatically go from up to down, but follow the direction I've given".

Is this possible?

For your information, I'm not looking for an answer on the question I refer to (using `index`/`match` or `vlookup`/`choose` or whatever), I'm looking for a general approach on my general question (not only to be used for `VLookup`, but also for `Match` or other search functions).

Comment: Excel O365 got `XLOOKUP()` and `XMATCH()` to do that. They have a parameter where you can specify to look bottom-up instead of top-down.

Comment: ^^^^ Which would suggest that this is an XY problem...

Comment: Well, there are ways to use `LOOKUP()` to retrieve a last match as sort of a reversed `INDEX()+MATCH()`, e.g.: `=LOOKUP(2,1/(A:A="X"),B:B)`. However, I don't think that is categorized under what you describe in your last two sentences.

Comment: For previous Excel versions.. I didn't see how a dummy sheet with transpose function doesn't solve the lookup thingy.. if just reverse direction, `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A1,100-ROW(),COLUMN()-1)` on Sheet2 A1 cell (assume maximum 100 line data on Sheet1 ), should do.

Comment: @JvdV: please write your comment about `XLookup()` as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment:

Microsoft365 got `XLOOKUP()` and `XMATCH()` to do that. They have a parameter where you can specify to look bottom-up instead of top-down.

Previous versions of Excel do have ways to retrieve the last match, however that is technically not the same as fixing the search direction bottom-up.